# Following an object in a constant background

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to track a single object (say a person) and follow the object (turn the camera). Assume that the background does not change.

I can't do a background subtraction since the camera angle also changes (following the person/object).

Can any one suggest me a simple get the blob of the moving object way to do this?

I am using OpenCv.

Comment: I wouldn't imagine there would be any actually simple algorithm (in generality or no devil in the details) to do that.

Comment: Have you looked into this article: http://www.intorobotics.com/how-to-detect-and-track-object-with-opencv/.

Answer (score 0):

Zhang's Real-time Compressive Tracking algorithm works brilliantly. There is a C++/opencv implementation at http://www4.comp.polyu.edu.hk/~cslzhang/CT/CT.htm. You'll need some other way to initally find the object so the tracker knows what to track.
It is fully described in this paper: http://www4.comp.polyu.edu.hk/~cslzhang/CT/eccv_ct_camera.pdf.